# Can I assign a string to a javascript object variable?

Tags: javascript

This seems an easy question for experienced developer, but I did not find the answer in stack overflow.

If I declare a variable like this, `var name = {};`

1. I think now my name is a object?

Can I assign a string to this variable name, like `name = "Foo";`

2. Will this work?
3. If this work, any cons for this?

(I know I can declare name as `var name = "";` But I remember in javascript, anything is object (including string, so string is also an object)).

Comment: you can do that, because in Js variables are not typed, like in Java for example. But if you know the variable is a string, why do that in the first place?

Comment: Googling JavaScript objects comes up with this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects Try looking around in places other than StackOverflow too, the resources are plentiful!

Comment: you could create example like this `name = {}; console.log(name); name = "string"; console.log(name);`

Comment: @yBrodsky Looking for ES4? Anyways, run time types are much inefficient. Better compile time types and structs. (represented as arrays)

Comment: @The_Grits Which line in your doc mentioned the answer for my question? I think if my question is not in stackoverflow, I can ask here, right? So, more developers can see it.

Comment: ToDownVoters: May I know why I got down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is dynamically typed language. In a nutshell, this means JS engine automatically decides what type to use depending on the type of value you are assigning to it. And it also means you can change the type of your variable anytime you want.

```
var name = {} //name is object

name = "" // name is now a string 

name = function (a) { return a + a } //it's now a function
```

The biggest con for this is that it spreads bugs:

- You can overwrite your variable  unintentionally
- Type can be changed though the value will be almost the same like `1 + "" // still 1 but is not a number anymore. It's a string now`
- You can always check what type you are using with `typeof()` function, but it won't help you in some cases `typeof( new Array() ) // is object`

There are plenty of nuances you'd need to learn about dynamic typing. So much that Microsoft decided to develop TypeScript - a typed superset of JavaScript invented to make the life of JS developers easier. It can do anything JS can plus several features from strictly typed languages

Answer (score 0):

As  yBrodsky  mentioned, you can do that in javascript as JS variables are not typed

you can use `typeof` operator to examine the type of the variable

```
msg = "hello";<br>
typeof msg ;
// returns "string"

msg = { a:"b"};<br>
typeof msg;                 
// returns "object"
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a dynamically typed language.Variable itself does not hold any datatype its the value inside the variable which defines its type.

> var name = {}; // will lead to name as "object" type 
>   name = ""; // will lead to name as "string" type 
>   name = [] ; // will lead to name as "object" type

In Javascript, everything is not an object. There are two things primitives and natives. 
These types are called primitives: null, undefined, number, string, boolean, symbol. 
When we do typeof primitives it will not return an object(except typeof null returns object).

Natives: String(), Number(), Boolean(), Array(), Object(), Function(), RegExp(), Date(), Error(), Symbol().
When we do typeof natives then it will return an object.

Native are created with the new keyword:

> var hey = new String("rajat");

And new will always return an object.

Comment: If you meant functions and etc., yeah. As far as my knowledge `Function` object overloads the `typeof` operator, resulting in `"function"`... however, `undefined`, null, numbers, strings, booleans and symbols (as far as my ES6 knowledge) aren't — they can be wrapped in objects though. However object accesses to numbers, strings and booleans are consumed (in some cases, use the type respective prototype object).